# How to always return JSON Objects (not Array) for ResponseEntity<Collection<?>>?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

According to [this](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#110) API guideline, in a response body, you must always return a JSON object (and not e.g. an array) as a top-level data structure to support future extensibility.

Is there a convenient and elegant way to achieve this with Spring (without wrapping each and every method's return type into a wrapper object)? Is there a configuration property or extension point of how to customize how spring serializes collections into its JSON representation?

So instead of

```
[
{
    "Prop1": "Val1",
    "Prop2": "Val2"
},
{
    ...
}
]
```

the following method

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Collection<MyType>> get() {
    …
}
```

should return

```
{
"MyType":[
    {
        "Prop1": "Val1",
        "Prop2": "Val2"
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try with [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html).

But, if you are going to modify the response after the controller handle, than i guess it would break the api documentation response format, in case if you have.

Answer (score -2):

based on my experince with c# you may do the following :-
prepare your list based on property,let say create a class called Prop with two property prop1 and prop2
instantiate List of your class

```
List<Prop> props=new List<Prop>();
```

then populate it with data

```
props.add(new Prop{prop1=value,prop2=value});
props.add(new Prop{prop1=value,prop2=value});
props.add(new Prop{prop1=value,prop2=value});
```

Note: if data come from database you may use for/foreach loop to add data into list

example

```
foreach(var data in dbData){
  props.add(new Prop{prop1=data.value1,prop2=data.value2});
}
```

and finally return object with list of value

enter code here

```
return new {MyType=props};
```